# Check if all setState methods are completed in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React's componentDidMount to carry out ajax calls operations and based on the returned results setting data to react state variable.

Now I need to use the react state variable values by calling several different methods as I want to do the operations on page load but somehow it's not working. I have also tried timeout but it's not consistent.

Anyone have any idea, what's going wrong?

Here is some sample code:

```
componentDidMount() {

 Helper.GetReview1Data().then(data => {
            this.setState({
                review1data: data
            }) 

        })

  Helper.GetReview2Data().then(data=> {
            this.setState({
                review2data: data
            })
   })

 this.get1Data()
 this.get2Data()
}
get1Data = () => {

console.log(this.state.review1data.map(i=>i.name))
console.log(this.state.review2data.map(i=>i.name))

}
get2Data = () => {
console.log(this.state.review2data.map(i=>i.name))
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is that `get1Data` should **only** be called after the state has been set from **both** async operations, then perhaps you could wrap each operation in a promise that resolves after `setState` has completed, then use `Promise.all()` to call `get1Data` after both promises have resolved, like this:

```
componentDidMount() {

  const promise1 = new Promise(resolve => {
    Helper.GetReview1Data().then(data => {
      this.setState({
        review1data: data
      }, resolve)
    })
  })

  const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => {
    Helper.GetReview2Data().then(data => {
      this.setState({
        review1data: data
      }, resolve)
    })
  })

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(this.get1Data)
  promise2.then(this.get2Data)
}

get1Data = () => {
  console.log(this.state.review1data.map(i=>i.name))
  console.log(this.state.review2data.map(i=>i.name))
}

get2Data = () => {
  console.log(this.state.review2data.map(i=>i.name))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `this.setState` is asynchronous you can use the call back functions like this

```
componentDidMount() {

 Helper.GetReview1Data().then(data => {
            this.setState({
                review1data: data
            }, () => { this.get1Data()}) 

        })

Helper.GetReview2Data().then(data=> {
            this.setState({
                review2data: data
            }, () =>{this.get2Data()})
   }) 
}

get1Data = () => {
    console.log(this.state.review1data.map(i=>i.name))
}

get2Data = () => {
    console.log(this.state.review2data.map(i=>i.name))
}
```

Comment: Although callback works fine. If want to use data from both states i.e. `review1data` and `review2data` in one method for e.g. `get1data ()` it doesn't.

Comment: To clarify more I want to use something like this `get1Data = () => {
    console.log(this.state.review1data.map(i=>i.name)) console.log(this.state.review2data.map(i=>i.name))
}`

Comment: As you are using both the functions in `componentDidMount`, both the functions data will be available  after the render, where do you want those data exactly ? let me tell you the data you want is available at every other functions after `componentDidMount`

Comment: The data should be available after `componentDidMount` but when I am using state data  `review1data` and `review2data` in single method e.g. `get1data ()` which is outside of `componentDidMount` but called on `componentDidMount` it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. As I want to use the data on page load I am calling method `get1data()` on `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

the issue stems from the fact that `Helper.GetReview1Data()` and `this.setState({review1data: data})` are asynchronous functions, but you are calling `this.get1Data()` synchronously afterwards.  This means the console.log will execute before you receive a response and set your state.

Try placing `this.get1Data()` as a callback after you have set your state like so:

```
 Helper.GetReview1Data().then(data => {
        this.setState({
            review1data: data
        }, this.get1Data) 

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

use setState({},()=>action when to do when it change state ) that will be executed after the setstate update the state
as this shape

```
 Helper.GetReview1Data().then(data => {
        this.setState({
            review1data: data
        }, this.get1Data) 

    })
```